# JSF 2.2 Generate PDF with xhtml - Seam alternative?

Tags: jsf, pdf, jakarta-ee, facelets, seam

Now that Seam is deprecated, and as [PDF where not given to anyone](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Home.html), what are the alternatives to generate a pdf file using facelets templating and backing beans ?

I did it with Seam some years ago and it was very smooth, and I would rather not do it programmatically (which in my opinion is never a good idea to generate views...)

Comment: Generating PDF files is beyond the responsibility of JSF.

Comment: @Tiny, with Seam PDF, it was not. JSF is a controller, if I choose to have my view rendered as a PDF, why not doing it ? This is just a format.
I don't see the difference with a mail render as https://github.com/codylerum/simple-email, as far as the format can be described with tags

Comment: As one of the solutions for creating pdf from anow xml you can use XSL-FO. But as soon as it does not provide rich templating abilities you can combine it with some template engine like Velocity. On one of the projects I was generating xml markup dynamically using Velocity and than converting this markup to pdf using xsl-fo.
If talking about jsf - can't remember anything except JBOSS Seam where it was PDF renderer for jsf pages.

Answer (score 0):

OK...
This [thread at jboss](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/179032?tstart=0) explains why it was not a so good idea and why it was deprecated. Thanks to Tiny and Trims for their insight.

I was confounding templating and JSF rendering.. like, in fact, Facelets is a good templating tool, but really focused on web.

More generic tools does exists to template PDF, like [FlyingSaucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) or [XDocReport as presented here](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/generating-pdf-files-using-odt-docx-templates)
It should be possible to create a XSL-FO through a [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) template and pass it to [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to generate the real PDF.

Comment: Still, I think that 95% of seam-pdf code was about creating an iText doc (pdf) from an xml, and it was very clean. I'm thinking now in merging this code in a non JSF related module (removing the templating, in fact) and seeing if using freemarker on top of it could recreate a killer solution to pdf generation